# How could I copy my docker container to a new computer?

Tags: docker

I am working on a prestashop project for my company, I created 3 containers : the server called `www`, `phpmyadmin` and `mysql`.

Today with new regulations I am switching to remote work. I would like to take my containers and move them to my laptop so I can still work from home.

I tried to save images as a `.tar` file and move them to my new laptop but nothing seems to work.

**How could I copy my containers so I'm able to work on my laptop?**

Comment: Why you don't copy the Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yml files and build the containers on the new computer?

Comment: you can take snapshot of containers & load them in your laptop try this https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-backup-and-restore-docker-containers/